# Why does the String type have keyword highlighting in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi, syntax-highlighting, delphi-ide

In the Delphi IDE the `String` type is highlighted as a keyword, similar to syntax elements like `const`, `function`, `begin`, `end`, or `class`. It seems to be the only type that gets this special highlighting, other types like `Integer`, `Boolean`, or `Double` have a "normal" color. Also there is no special color for other types similar to String like `AnsiString`, `WideString` or `UnicodeString`.

Out of curiosity: What is the reason the String type is treated special in IDE syntax highlighting?

Comment: The reason is that `String` is considered a reserved word and thus gets keyword highlighting. This is different from other types like `Integer` which are not considered a reserved word. For example you can create a variable named "Integer", but you cannot create a variable named "String".

Comment: The reason is you haven't searched existing questions and answers. You can redefine `type Integer= String` but you cannot redefine `type String= Integer`.

Comment: @AmigoJack: No problem with closing this as a duplicate question. Just wanted to summarize the information from the linked answer.